# Can I use the @TestSetup from a separate test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I have a class I want to test that has an associated test class with it. I am wondering if I use a TestDataFactory class if the @TestSetup annotation will allow me to access the data inserted from my test class

```
public class FunctionalClass {
    //logic that needs to be tested
}

@IsTest
public class TestFunctionalClass {
    //unit tests that test FunctionClass logic
    //query for data that is setup in TestDataFactory.class
}

@IsTest
public class TestDataFactory {
    @TestSetup
    static void setup() {
        //insert test data
    }

    public static List<ExternalObject__x> getExternalObjectTestData() {
        //return mock external objects
    }
}
```

I know I can just have the setup method in my TestFunctionalClass but I'd like for all test data to be in my DataFactory class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@TestSetup` is only applicable in the same test class.

You should take this approach to make your `TestDataFactory` class reusable and that `setup()` method can be accessed from `@TestSetup` method of calling class.

```
public class FunctionalClass {
    //logic that needs to be tested

}

@IsTest
public class TestFunctionalClass {

    @TestSetup static void prepareData()
    {
        TestDataFactory.setup();
    }

    static testMethod void validateData()
    {
        //unit tests that test FunctionClass logic
        //query for data that is setup in TestDataFactory.class
    }

}

@IsTest
public class TestDataFactory {
    static void setup() {
        //insert test data
    }

    public static List<ExternalObject__x> getExternalObjectTestData() {
        //return mock external objects
    }
}
```